# .net version targeted by Excel - TLS issue

Tags: c#, excel, ssl, servicepointmanager

I have a C# dll build with target framework 4.6.1 that I am using in an Excel Add-in as well as in an executable (also build with target framework 4.6.1).

I am not specifying ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol in my dll so it can use the highest one supported by the OS as per Microsoft recommendations.

But when I check the ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol when running the dll via the Excel add-in it is set to **Ssl3|Tls**

and when i run the same dll within the exe the ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol is **Tls|Tls11|Tls12|Tls13**

I see this behavior on the same machine.

I know the support for security protocols varies based on the version of the framework.

Would appreciate help with understanding behavior. I am trying avoid having to hard code the Tls version in my DLL.

Thanks